# Need Help Getting Sign In With Apple Working With B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm a newbie developer trying to get Sign In With Apple working but am having a really hard time with one part.  So I've been following these instructions (https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple) and I get stuck at the "Creating the OIDC metadata endpoint" part.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this and it seems so basic.  I did take that contents of that JSON code snippet they gave and put it into a JSON file in a Blob Storage Location, but it of course does not in the required "/.well-known/openid-configuration".  How do you go about creating this?  I found this other tutorial that made reference to using a WebApp but again this is a bit over my head at this point and I've been searching for days:  https://idmlab-e.eidentity.jp/2019/06/enable-sign-in-with-apple-on-azure-ad.html

Update - the procedures posted by the person who replied below worked and I was able to get Sign in With Apple mostly working but only with https://example-app.com/redirect as my ReplyURI.  It looks like you have to develop your own similar callback site to parse the results and do any other downstream processing that this site did for demo purposes.  I can't get that to work still though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Azure Function and the contents present in this link: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple/source-code/B2CSignInWithApple/SigninWithApple_OpenidConfiguration

It defined the route
"**route**": "signinwithapple/.well-known/openid-configuration"

If you are new to Azure Function/Function App then refer this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio

Comment: Oh geez, thanks.  I'll have to try this out later this evening but looks simple for a newbie to follow along.

Comment: So I had some time to play with this and I just can't get this to work even with this Github code.  When I use it as my ReplyURI, the Apple Redirect site says it can't find this webpage.  I can verify that it's there when visiting manually, it's just on the redirect part only.  What could be causing this?  It only works with https://example-app.com/redirect site

Answer (score 0):

There has been an update to the Apple endpoint since then, so you don't have to create your own OIDC Metadata endpoint anymore. See this article (there is a step that says you need to complete the first guide you followed up until the Create your own OIDC Metadata endpoint step): https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/post-ga-revisit-of-quot-sign-in-with-apple-quot-for-azure-ad-b2c/ba-p/1083814

Comment: Great, thanks, I managed to get this working both ways (using Apple metadata endpoint or that GitHub source code).  It turns out there's a minor flaw in the way that Microsoft wrote their documentation for how to setup Sign in With Apple, particularly on the procedure on how to generate the secret key.  They have an example program that ends with .app or something along those lines but you need to use the .service program name instead.  Once I generated and changed my token it started to work.

Side note - their oAuth Resp link will not parse out the full User Data sent by Apple at this time

Comment: I see, yes I ran into the same problem with generating the secret key. And also yes, I tried my best to parse out the User data but it doesn't seem to be possible. If you look at  the LinkedIn Custom Provider for B2C they have a json parser to get items from the LinkedIn response, but I tried a few ways to get the Apple response but it didn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Is it me or does this Azure B2C concept seem to be a bit half baked?  Firebase appears to parse this info out and setup was a breeze.  Plus they have a good Javascript library to make a slick custom login UI.  I try doing this with CSS on Azure and I can make it look better than the default templates, but still nothing like Firebase.

Comment: Wow really? Good to know on Firebase. Did you ever figure out how to get the name from the Apple response by chance?

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't automatically parse it out.  The only option is to setup B2C to ask for their First and Last name, which I think might be against the Sign In With Apple's terms of service